# Handling the ctrl keys with keypress

Tags: javascript, events, keypress, ctrl

I've looked around a lot and I know you can detect the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, etc) with the keydown event in javascript and it's often used so that the event isn't captured by other processes however I want to handle it through the keypress event (the purpose being handling through one event rather than 2 and hopefully allowing for consistency when using other keyboard shortcuts for the same function) now it seems like it should be possible after all the keypress event object has Boolean properties for <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>, etc. and the character code for keypress events that do go through are different then the key itself (for example z keypress event is charCode 122 where <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> keypress event is charCode 26). So the question is, is there a way to prevent the default from intercepting the ctrl keys so that the keypress event can handle them?

for my particular instance I'm using chrome but I also want general answers.

UPDATE

ive found that all of the default of the ctrl keys can be prevented (for example ctrl+s attempting to save the page) using the from inside the keydown event like this

```
$('element').keydown(function(event){
    if(event.ctrlKey){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

(note: this only prevents the defaults that are preventable things like ctrl+t for a new tab in chrome can not be prevented)

however the problem here is that this also stops the keypress event from occurring is there a way to then pass the event to the keypress event in a way that will have the keypress properties (meaning things like the charCode will now be defined)

Answer (score -1):

Reading this from another site it states -

> Keyboard events is one of wilder parts of frontend development. There
>   are inconsistencies and cross-browser problems.
>
> But still there are recipes which help to cope with ordinary
>   situations easily.
>
> There are following keyboard events:
>
> **keydown**
>   A key is pressed down.
>   **keypress**
>   A character key is pressed.
>   **keyup**
>   A key is released.
>
> There is a fundamental difference between keypress and keydown.
>
> Keydown triggers on any key press and gives scan-code.
>      Keypress triggers after keydown and gives char-code, but it is guaranteed for character keys only.

Given this, the control key can't be captured by keypress because it doesn't generate a character.

More information can be found here on even more specific information.

http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events

Hope this helps

Comment: I think you missed the whole point I wanted to capture it with the key press event that was the whole purpose of the question

Comment: Like I specifically said I know you can capture it with key down but I want to do it with key press

Comment: I see your issue.  Mind if I change my answer.  It seems you won't be able to do this since keydown and keyup are different than key press.

Comment: Yes please keypress just so you know is a more processed version of key down and key up and it includes things that the others don't such as the shift and ctrl being part of the same event. With keydown shift+a gives you two events the shift and the a with keypress it gives you one event for the A

Comment: I've updated my answer to include why the control key alone can't be captured alone with keypress.  I've quoted the site and given you the sites URL in case you wanted a deeper knowledge of it.

Comment: But I wasn't trying to capture the ctrl key alone I was trying capture key combinations like ctrl+z

Comment: And some of those do capture currently but the majority are either intercepted or do nothing.

Comment: Researching this and coding up some example code to capture key codes with keypress it seems that keypress doesn't register anything when using any control key combination (with control C or control Z).  I suspect it is because it doesn't generate an actual character.

Comment: An event listener for the keypress event on a non text area element in chrome returns character code 26 I don't necessarily need it to return a string I just need it to return a consistent character code so that it doesn't matter if I hit ctrl z or undo (yes I know there isn't a standard undo button I just want to be able to handle anything that returns the same ascii code)

Comment: Hmm.  In jQuery $(document).keypress(function (e) does not capture anything when the control key is pressed.

Comment: But press ctrl z and you should get something just console log the event and you can find the character code

Comment: It did for me I have an angular (angular inherits from jquery) keypress listener on a canvas element

Comment: It does not capture control C though.

Comment: No it doesn't thus my question. Ctrl c is intercepted by some default

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99383/discussion-between-dale-and-binvention).